# Do I need to obtain a visa prior to visiting Malawi as a US Citizen?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, malawi

I'm researching visa requirements for a safari in 2017 and from what it looks like most of the countries will give a visa on arrival at the border.

However, looking at Malawi it's saying I need to obtain a visa prior:

https://travel.state.gov/content/passports/en/country/malawi.html

What the site doesn't really specify is if one can be obtained at the border. Unless I'm missing it.

So, do I need to get one before departure from the US, or will a visa on arrival be granted at the border?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, while all the answers here were awesome, I got mixed responses. So I ended up contacting the US Consulate in Lilongwe, Malawi.

Here was their response:

> Entry visas for U.S. travelers are available upon arrival in Malawi at
>   both of the international airports, Lilongwe and Blantyre, as well as
>   at border crossings.  You will have to complete a one-page visa
>   application form and pay the USD $75 (U.S. dollars only) but it’s
>   fairly routine at this point.  I’m copying our official announcement
>   below for your reference.
>
> http://lilongwe.usembassy.gov/service/routine-messages2/entry-fee-for-malawi2.html

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to obtain one beforehand, you can still get one on arrival according to [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=US&AR=00&PASSTYPES=PASS&DE=MW&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C)

You do need a visa however, according to the Malawi [embassy](http://www.malawiembassy-dc.org/index.php?page=visa-information) in Washington and they don't mention anything about visas on arrival. You could always request one before leaving to be safe, as the processing time is just [5 days](http://www.malawiembassy-dc.org/index.php?page=application-requirements). They've introduced [visa](http://af.reuters.com/article/malawiNews/idAFL5N11Z1KZ20150929) requirements for Europeans and Asians and for those who can get one on arrival it's unclear what the procedure is

> The Government of Malawi will issue visas within Malawi but procedures
>   for obtaining them have not yet been published.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, United States nationals are among those who need a visa when going to Malawi, according to the [Embassy of the Republic of Malawi web site](http://www.malawiembassy-dc.org/index.php?page=visa-information)

> Application Requirements
>   To apply for a Visa, the Passport must be valid for at least 6 months beyond the date of intended departure.
>
> TYPES OF VISA | COST: Tourist and Business Validity
>
> - Transit (7 days) US $70.00
> - 3 months single entry from date of issue US $100.00
> - 6 months multiple entry from date of issue US $220.00
> - One year multiple entry from date of issue US $300.00
>
> Application Requirements
>
> - 2 application forms Visa Application Forms
> - 2 Passport-size photos
> - Fees can be paid by money order, bank certified check or cash (The
>     Embassy will not accept personal checks as a form of payment)
> - Onward ticket
> - Valid Passport (at least six months before expiry date with
>     enough unused pages)
> - Copy of a letter from the applicant’s Organization or invitation letter.
> - Copy of sponsor’s Residential Status in Malawi (i.e. Permit or Malawi Passport if Malawian)
> - Return Pre-Paid Envelope addressed to the applicant.
>
> *Please note:
>   Application and all required documents MUST be sent in DUPLICATE to the Consular section at the Embassy.
>   In most cases, applications will be processed in 5 working days. However, for nationals of India, Nigeria, Bangladesh, China, Burundi, Rwanda and Pakistan, applications may take up to 4 weeks.
>   Drop off time: 09:30 am to 12:30pm from Mondays to Thursdays.*

Answer (score 1):

Visas on Arrival are available only in cases where a standard visa can not be obtained (ie in countries without a Malawi consular post, extended travel away from your country of residence, etc).

Approval for a VOA needs to be obtained before you arrive from the Immigration Department in Malawi.  You can't just simply hop on a plane and be granted a VOA.

As the US has a Malawi Embassy, you likely will be limited to getting the visa through them.

http://www.immigration.gov.mw/visa.html

Answer (score 1):

I am an American that live in Malawi

Visas as issued at the International Airport upon arrival in Lilongwe

Visas can be obtained at the Border crossings by filling a one page Visa document

There are several types of visas but please note that although your Visa may be valid for 3, 6 or 12 months (single or multiple entry) you must check in at the nearest Immigrations Office after 30 days in the country.